# On duplicate key update - increase by 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I am inserting search terms into a database, and when I run it to test, I was seeing duplicates inserted into the database. I was able to solve that, but, now I am inserting, and it no longer inserts as a duplicate, but I am trying to get the on duplicate to work - and the on duplicate updates the popularity by 2 each time? what do I have wrong here?

```
$entryDate = date("c");
$insertsearchquery="insert into article_searches (termSafe,entryDate) values (\"$termSafe\",\"$entryDate\") on duplicate key update popularity=popularity+1";

mysql_query($insertsearchquery);
```

I have a UNIQUE key set for both termSafe and entryDate.

```
TABLE `article_searches` (
`id`  bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT ,
`termSafe` varchar(150) ,
`entryDate`  varchar(255),
`popularity` tinyint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE INDEX `termSafe` USING BTREE (`termSafe`),
UNIQUE INDEX `entryDate` USING BTREE (`entryDate`)
)
```

Although I just deleted the entryDate unique Index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is because you have a UNIQUE (termSafe) and UNIQUE (entryDate), perhaps you just want a UNIQUE (termSafe,entryDate).

Bear in mind `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.. you should use PDO or `mysqli_*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the two unique indexes and create only one:

```
 create unique index idx_article_searches_termSafe_EntryDate on article_searches(termSafe, EntryDate);
```

When using `on duplciate key update`, the behavior can be ill-defined when more than one unique constraint violation is detected.  I think it is doing the update twice, once for each constraint.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is the warning in the documentation:

> In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

Comment: When I create that unique index, I get an error that my max key length is 1000 bytes. And even if I drop the UNIQUE on my entryDate -it still updates the popularity by 2.

Comment: @Jacob . . . You should edit the question an put the table definition in.  If the keys really need to be over 1000 bytes long, then you have a problem with a unique index.  However, if it works on one column, then the date should only be 4 or 8 bytes.